# Why $\cos (x)>0$?

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align*}\cos '(x)=-\sin (x), \sin '(x)=\cos (x)\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

> We assert that there exist positive numbers $x$ such that $\cos (x)=0$.  For  suppose this is not so. Since $\cos (0)=1$, it then follows that $\color{Green}{\cos (x)>0}$ for all $x>0$,...

Why $\cos (x)>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\cos$ is continuous; by the intermediate value theorem, to get from $\cos(0)=1$ to a negative value (say $\cos(y) < 0$ for $y>0$, by contradiction), there would be a point $x\in(0,y)$ such that $\cos x =0$. Which contradicts your first assumption.

Comment: Hi, I simply think of the fact $\cos(\pi)=-1$

Comment: Yes, but you start by trying to prove something *by contradiction* (that is, you start by assuming $\cos x\neq 0$ for all $x> 0$, in order to get a contradiction); based on this **(false)** assumption and the fact that $\cos$ is continuous, you can prove by another proof by contradiction that $\cos$ must remain strictly positive. Of course, this is not the case, but that's the whole point of the proof in the first place — derive something you know to be false.

Comment: @HyperGroups: Presumably the quoted paragraph is a fragment of a proof that the number $\pi$ exists.

Comment: @ClementC. got it, if $cos(x)<0$ then there exists $cos(x)=0$

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, the after paragraph is about constructing such $\pi$

Comment: This is a very strange proof...(not yours ClementC but the proof by contradiction in the OP's question).